# 2 Table Query Proper Protocol

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search results query that I need to modify so that it does not show products that are already sold. So here is the non modified select statement as it exists currently:

```
SELECT id, cid, sid, posttitle, postdetails, city, `state`, zipcode 
FROM posts 
ORDER BY datepublished DESC
```

I need to modify that so that it looks to the `orderdetails table under`DetailProductID` to see if it exists and if it does to now show it; So in essence in English it would be something like this:

```
SELECT id, cid, **etc** 
FROM posts 
WHERE posts.id NOT IN orderdetails.DetailProductID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
id, cid, sid, posttitle, postdetails, city, state, zipcode 
FROM posts 
where posts.id not in (select DetailProductID from orderdetails)
ORDER BY datepublished DESC
```

or using a clever left join

```
SELECT 
posts.id, posts.cid, posts.sid, posts.posttitle, posts.postdetails, posts.city, posts.state, posts.zipcode 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN orderdetails ON orderdetails.DetailProductID = posts.id
where orderdetails.DetailProductID is null
ORDER BY posts.datepublished DESC
```

Comment: I would use the left join because it will perform better for larger data. The "NOT IN" condition might have hundreds if not thousands of IDs and this will slow it down. Also in the long run, as data grows, it will slow down performance even further. Basically, for more than 20 items in the "IN" statement i would use the join. Also, subqueries are generally not recomended.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, cid, etc from posts WHERE posts.id NOT IN (Select DetailProductID from orderdetails)
```